# Publisher Actions being automatically included in Managed Package

Tags: managed-package

I just noticed that a new version of one of my Managed Packages has some of the standard global Publisher Actions included as components. Pretty sure I never added them to my package, but I can't see why they would have been included...and of course, they now can't be deleted - unhelpful.

Anyone seen anything similar? Trying to work out why it happened so can avoid in future...

Comment: Can you post your edit as an answer? Self-answering questions is encouraged if you figure out the solution to your own problem.

Answer (score 3):

So I looked at another packaging org, and sure enough, they have been automatically included in that package for when a new version is uploaded, and they can't be removed via the add to  packaging options.

The reason I think they are being included is that the package includes custom page layouts for Accounts and Contacts. Because page layouts for Accounts and Contacts include the Global Publisher Layout by default, the actions are included the package. This appears to be true even when Chatter is not enabled in the Packaging Org (which is the case in this second Org)

As a workaround, even though the actions can't be removed from the package, I could delete the standard Global Publisher actions because they haven't already been included in a package.

So beware - if you have a package with page layouts that include standard objects like Accounts and Contacts, make sure you aren't inadvertently including Global Publisher Actions!

Comment: QQ; where in the metadata can you find the publisher actions? Are they in their own separate files? Thanks.

Comment: There are under quickactions

Answer (score 2):

We had a similar issue with the Actions being pulled into our betas. We selected the link to each Action from the package manifest and deleted it.

Here's a handy Chrome Javascript URL that itemizes what's being added to a package. Use it on the package upload page that shows the manifest. I'll be running this puppy before every version upload now.

```
javascript:var v;if(v=prompt("package version")){var added=[];var rows=document.getElementsByClassName("dataRow");for(var i=0;i<rows.length;i++){var row=rows[i];var cells=row.getElementsByTagName("td");var version=cells[6].innerText;if(version==v+" - Current"||version==""){var name=cells[2].innerText;var parent=cells[3].innerText;var type=cells[4].innerText;added.push({name:name,parent:parent,type:type})}}added.sort(function(a,b){if(a.type!=b.type){return a.type>b.type?1:-1}if(a.parent!=b.parent){return a.parent>b.parent?1:-1}return a.name>b.name?1:-1});var table=document.createElement("table");var lastType=null;for(var i=0;i<added.length;i++){var item=added[i];if(item.type!=lastType){var row=document.createElement("tr");var cell=document.createElement("td");var header=document.createElement("h3");header.innerText=item.type;cell.appendChild(header);cell.setAttribute("colspan",2);row.appendChild(cell);table.appendChild(row)}lastType=item.type;var row=document.createElement("tr");var cell1=document.createElement("td");cell1.innerText=item.parent;row.appendChild(cell1);var cell2=document.createElement("td");cell2.innerText=item.name;row.appendChild(cell2);table.appendChild(row)}var style=document.createElement("style");style.setAttribute("type","text/css");style.innerHTML="td{padding:0px 10px}h3{margin-bottom:0px}";var body=document.createElement("body");body.appendChild(style);body.appendChild(table);while(document.hasChildNodes()){document.removeChild(document.lastChild)}document.appendChild(body)}
```

Answer (score 1):

All -

This is a known issue and Salesforce is working on a tentative fix. Please refer to the link listed below:

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T225AAC

Thanks!